# Secure way of using private MD5 key in javascript algorith?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, payment

I want integrate on-line payments with my web (html + jquery). Easiest way is just send form on specific link. One of parameters is signature. Signature is hash from from fields and private key. Problem is I don't wanna expose my private key in javascript code. Is any secure way to do it?

Here is test code for form:
http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html#creating_new_order_form
and signature generating algoritm:
http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html#references_form_signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is... No. Well, maybe but not really.

You cannot do the whole process in Javascript securely as it requires you to load the key into the users browser. That's an instant security game over.

What you *can* do is have a server (key store) somewhere that holds your private key and encrypts messages on demand. That would prevent end users seeing your private key, but it just moves the problem down the line - how do you know that the browser making the request is a genuine user and not someone malicious? If you just sign anything you're presented, you may as well skip the security entirely. If you're going to have a server anyway, why not use it to serve the webpages and validate form data too?

So really, you need something server-side that validates user input, checks that it's sane/untampered and then signs the message and passes it on.

You have to ask yourself why you need to do this from within a browser... The whole point of signing a message is to prove who it comes from. If it's coming from someone else's browser and you know nothing about the message, why would you sign it as authentic and coming from you?

Comment: So, if my server support PHP I can create php script, post to that script, sign the message and pass it to payment endpoint?

Comment: Yes, that would work - you would then be as secure as however you store the key on the PHP server. Obviously, you'd still need to sanity check the data coming from the user (assume malicious intent) before signing, but as long as the signing happens in code running on hardware you own/control, it's a huge improvement. Note that once signed, you could either pass to the payment gateway directly or back to the browser. A user attempt to change data would invalidate the signature